# How can I code for subtitles in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R Studio, and noticed that there's a little orange # between the code window and the console that lists the subtitle within your code that you're working under.  How can I indicate a label for a subtitle?  is it

```
#subtitle#
```

or

```
#subtitle
```

or what? Neither of these seems to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a single line, add `#`, your label, then 4 or more hyphens after your label

```
# My chunk ----
```

Alternatively, you can insert a code section with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on Mac